# Pandoc Markdown: Multiparagraph list with code blocks

Tags: markdown, pandoc, github-flavored-markdown

The whole documentation on Lists on the [Pandoc site](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#lists) seems wrong or at best a huge mess.

I mostly sorted out the way to deal with multiple paragraphs in lists, but I am stuck with the following combination: **The text paragraph following a code block paragraph falls off the list**. That is, **a code block paragraph breaks the list** (as seen in the latex .tex output file; use option -t tex).

If the following Markdown text is in file test.md and I use Pandoc as
`pandoc -t latex test.md -o test.pdf`

**How should the following Markdown text be formatted so that Paragraph 3 falls inside item 1 of the list and is aligned with its first paragraph**?

````
   1. List item. Paragraph 1

   ```javascript
        // Second paragraph is a code block. If start at column 6, code shows ok.
        // Additional indentation only moves code block further right
        // Notice code block tag/backticks starts at column 1 though!!
        //  If it starts at col 2+, code block w/ tag is messed up as all code block.
        var x = 3
        print( "Pandoc has made a mess out of Markdown!" )
   ```

        Paragraph 3. However list is broken and Par 3 falls off.
   2. List item
````

It should show as:

1. List item. Paragraph 1

`// Second paragraph is a code block. If start at column 6, code shows ok.
    // Additional indentation only moves code block further right
    // Notice code block tag/backticks starts at column 1 though!!
    //  If it starts at col 2+, code block w/ tag is messed up as all code block.
    var x = 3
    print( "Pandoc has made a mess out of Markdown!" )`

```
   Paragraph 3. However list is broken and Par 3 falls off.
```

2. List item

But instead shows as

1. List item. Paragraph 1

`// Second paragraph is a code block. If start at column 6, code shows ok.
     // Additional indentation only moves code block further right
     // Notice code block tag/backticks starts at column 1 though!!
     //  If it starts at col 2+, code block w/ tag is messed up as all code block.
     var x = 3
     print( "Pandoc has made a mess out of Markdown!" )`

Paragraph 3. However list is broken and Par 3 falls off.

2. List item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to use the right combination of indents and newlines:

````
1. List item, no indention

    This paragraph is indented by two tabs (four spaces). 
    Put separating newlines below and above the following code chunk:

    ```javascript
    // This code chunk is indented by two tabs (four spaces)
    var x = 3
    print("Pandoc has made a mess out of Markdown!")
    ```

    Paragraph 3 is indented by two tabs.

2. List item, no indention
````

This yields

[image]

Comment: Great, that did it. I think I once nailed it by chance, but this has been quite a source of frustration. Did you followed that combination from the panda docs? If so, I totally missed it.

Comment: Yes, i did. :-)

Comment: :-) Well, your second and following paragraphs are indented 4 spaces wrt column 1, where the list counters are. That's it, it starts at column 5. That's not what the docs say. Actually this combination is no where to find explained there. The closest is the rule when a code block follows the list marker: "Subsequent paragraphs must begin 2 columns  after the last character of the list marker" ! I find these docs almost as bad as that for hexdump...